# How to convert whole column of dates/times from one time zone to another in R?

Tags: r, timezone, posixct, posixlt

[image]

Every row has a different origintimezone. I need to make use of the standardformat_new column which is in the origintimezone time to create a new column where the time follows the com_timezonenames.

A simplified version would be something like this

```
a = ymd_hms('2017-10-10 10:20:00',tz = 'Australia/Sydney')
a
with_tz(a, tz = 'Singapore')
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

However, when I'm applying a similar code to that above, I am met with the following error.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I have tried making a for loop to run the whole list but the dataset of over a few hundred thousand makes it unfeasible.

REPREX as reqeusted
This is what i have initially.

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

```
structure(list(com_country = c("SG", "AU", "NZ", "UK", "AU", 
"AU"), orderdate_local = c("9/20/2017 4:47:35 AM", "9/30/2017 7:00:00 AM", 
"9/20/2017 1:37:14 AM", "9/18/2017 9:38:34 PM", "9/30/2017 3:07:29 AM", 
"9/30/2017 10:17:01 AM"), origincountry = c("US", "AU", "UK", 
"AU", "AU", "AU")), .Names = c("com_country", "orderdate_local", 
"origincountry"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

orderdate_local is given in the origincountry timezone so i need to include map the country code over to the tz value.

```
##getting origin timezone from countrycode
dd$origintimezone <- mapvalues(dd$origincountry, 
                                      from=c("AU", "UK", "US"), 
to=c("Australia/Sydney","Europe/London","America/Toronto"))
```

thereafter i need to convert orderdate_local into the standard POSIXlt format so i can use the strptime function

```
dd$standardformat_new <- strptime(dd$orderdate_local,format="%m/%d/%Y 
%I:%M:%S %p")
dd$com_timezonenames <- mapvalues(dd$com_country, 
                      from=c("AU","MY","NZ","SG","PH","HK","UK","TH"), 
                              to=c("Australia/Sydney", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur", "Pacific/Auckland","Asia/Singapore","Asia/Manila","Asia/Hong_Kong","Europe/London","Asia/Bangkok"))
```

This is what we have as of now.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

EDITED after trying several options with your reprex and running into a invalid 'tz' value when trying to force it to accept different time zones for different elements of a date time vector, I dug through the documentation to find this:

> R date-time vectors cannot hold elements with non-uniform time zones

It looks like you'll have to store the date time in UTC time, which is really frustrating.

Here's how you'd do that:

```
dd$standardformat_new <- force_tzs(mdy_hms(dd$orderdate_local), 
                                   tzones = dd$com_timezonenames)
```

The above code uses the lubridate package to both convert your nonstandard character vector representing the date and time to a date-time object, takes as an input the Olson Name timezones you generated, and produces a vector of the UTC times corresponding to the local times in the specified timezones. This is unfortunately not as nice and readable, but it does have the advantage of accurately representing the relative times between time zones and allowing you to perform further computations on the vector as a date-time object. You can, of course, choose to display the data with a different time zone (just set `tzone_out` to some other time zone), but it has to be the same time zone for all of the values.

And thanks for putting together that [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html). I hope this was somewhat helpful

Comment: Thanks for the help but it takes a very long time for the whole function to run. I just added the reprex above, many thanks if you could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        ##getting origin timezone from countrycode
        dd$origintimezone <- mapvalues(dd$origincountry, 
                               from=c("AU", "UK", "US"), 

        to=c("Australia/Sydney","Europe/London","America/Toronto"))

        ##getting com_country timezone 
        dd$com_timezonenames <- mapvalues(dd$com_country, 

        from=c("AU","MY","NZ","SG","PH","HK","UK","TH"), 
                                  to=c("Australia/Sydney", 
        "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur","Pacific/Auckland","Asia/Singapore","Asia/Manila","Asia/Hong_Kong","Europe/London","Asia/Bangkok"))




         dd$origintimezoneTIME <- force_tzs(mdy_hms(dd$orderdate_local),tzones = 
         dd$origintimezone,tzone_out = "UTC")
         dd_table <- data.table(A = 1:nrow(dd),
                       origintimezoneTIME_UTC = dd$origintimezoneTIME,
                       com_timezonenames = dd$com_timezonenames,
                       com_country = dd$com_country,
                       orderdate_local = dd$orderdate_local,
                       origincountry = dd$origincountry,
                       origintimezone = dd$origintimezone)

       dd_table[ , com_countryTIME := format(toTz(origintimezoneTIME_UTC, "UTC", 
       com_timezonenames), tz=com_timezonenames), by=A ]
```

Code with help from this page [Adjusting UTC date/time to different time zones by reference in `lubridate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057385/adjusting-utc-date-time-to-different-time-zones-by-reference-in-lubridate)

Answer (score 0):

```
dl%>%
  mutate(time1 = as.POSIXct(strptime(orderdate_local,format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",tz="GMT")),
         time2 = ymd_hms(unlist(lapply(seq(length(time1)),
                                       function(x) {format(with_tz(force_tz(time1[x], com_timezonenames[x]),"GMT"), "%F %T")}))),
         time3 = ymd_hms(unlist(lapply(seq(length(time2)), 
                                       function(x) {format(with_tz(time2[x], origintimezone[x]), "%F %T")}))))
```

another simpler solution without any fancy library